# Things cheap in UK London comparing to India

Tags: india, london, tips-and-tricks, shopping

What are the things that are `cheap in UK-London when compared to India-Bangalore`. I am currently in London for a couple of weeks stay. I have decided to purchase few things like `Mobile phone, External Hard disk, Ear phone, Power Bank, Trimmer, Watch, Shoes, IPod`. So my question is, whether we can buy these things as cheaper when compared to India? If yes where these can be purchase?

Comment: You are asking people to do an awful lot of research there...

Comment: @Moo Not asking people to research. Asking to provide some suggestions if they have in mind. Do you mean that Stack-Exchange-Travel is not a right place to ask these questions?

Comment: WINE!!  Wine (other than Indian-grown wine) is astoundingly expensive in India due to the taxes.

Comment: @Moo Someone who travels a lot between UK and India will know from experience; I assume this is why the asker asked on a travel site

Answer (score 4):

> If yes where these can be purchase?

The bulk of what you are looking for: mobiles, external hard drives, ear phones, power banks, and watch are sold all over London.  But if you want to see lots of electronic stores in one district, invariably the answer is [Tottenham Court Road](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tottenham_Court_Road).

The 'district' begins at the [Tottenham Court Road Tube Station](https://tfl.gov.uk/tube/stop/940GZZLUTCR/tottenham-court-road-underground-station) and extends north for roughly 1/2 km on either side.  To help recognise it, here's a screen cap from Google maps...

[image]

You asked about price.  The close proximity of these shops forces them to be sharply competitive. And moreover, there is an unspoken 'ethos' that all prices are the 'starting price' and subject to negotiation.  You asked about comparison to similar products in India. Many of the staff in these shops claim south Asian heritage and should be able to honestly quote you the differential (if there is one). They would also be able to signpost you to a reliable source of India's tax and custom regulations.

---

There is also an interesting College Computer Fair just off Tottenham Court Road near [Goodge Street](https://tfl.gov.uk/tube/stop/940GZZLUGDG/goodge-street-underground-station).  It runs on the weekends, but always double check the [College Computer Fair](http://www.collegecomputerfair.co.uk/) site for details.

---

Finally, some of the items in your shopping list were items of clothing. There are many cheap places, but the [Petticoat Lane Market](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petticoat_Lane_Market) is legendary for it's prices and selection.  Here's an image from the Wiki...

[image]

Source: [Wiki entry for Petticoat Lane Market](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petticoat_Lane_Market)

The nearest tube stop is [Aldgate East Station](https://tfl.gov.uk/hub/stop/940GZZLUADE/aldgate-east-underground-station).

Comment: Isn't buying online cheaper in the UK?

Comment: @JonathanReez  how do you barter with Amazon? Also online sales in the UK are generally inclusive of VAT and the OP will undoubtedly be seeking relief https://www.gov.uk/tax-on-shopping/taxfree-shopping in the form of a receipt.

Comment: Can bartering get you a better price than Amazon though? :) And isn't it possible to refund VAT from online shopping?

Comment: @JonathanReez effectiveness at bartering varies from person-to-person. If you have an answer promoting online sales, you can add it and we'll see how it compares.  This answer is about the retail experience and gives a few tips-and-techniques about London markets. It has to stand 'as is', sorry

Comment: Good answer; ironically most of the clothes on sale in Petticoat Lane Market are made in / imported from the Indian subcontinent, and usually sold by stallholders with roots there too!